# why $E \ge K_{G(K/E)}$ is true?

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-explanation

The following is a part of a very long proof of Galois Theorem (Thm 53.6) from A First Course in Abstract Algebra - Fraleigh :

[image]

$E \le K_{G(K/E)}$ is very obvious but no matter how much I try I can't figure out why $E \ge K_{G(K/E)}$ is true. The mentioned two theorem for this inequality in the text look irrelevant. Please help, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea is that for any element $\alpha \notin E$ the degree of $\mathrm{irr}(\alpha, E)$ is at least $2$, hence there is some element $\beta \neq \alpha$ conjugate to $\alpha$. Then the conjugation isomorphism $\psi_{\alpha, \beta}$ extends to an automorphism of $K$ (here you need that $K$ is a normal extension) by the isomorphism theorem.

Thus for every element $\alpha \notin E$ you can find an automorphism of $K$ that does not fix $\alpha$, hence $K_{G(K/E)} \leq E$.

Comment: I still couldn't get the last part : "hence $K_{G(K/E)} \leq E$". I understood all of your answer but how do you conclude from them any element in $K_{G(K/E)}$ is an element of $E$ too?

Comment: By definition, $K_{G(K/E)}$ is the largest subfield of $K$ that is fixed by *all* automorphisms in $G(K/E)$. Now, for any element $\alpha \notin E$ we can find an element of $G(K/E)$ that does not fix $\alpha$, hence $\alpha$ is not fixed by all of $G(K/E)$ so $\alpha \notin K_{G(K/E)}$. Thus we have shown the implication 'if $\alpha \notin E$ then $\alpha \notin K_{G(K/E)}$', which is logically equivalent (contrapositive) to the implication 'if $\alpha \in K_{G(K/E)}$ then $\alpha \in E$', i.e.; $K_{G(K/E)} \leq E$